# How logging to be done into a file in a specific folder

Tags: swift, cocoa

Some macOS apps write their logs into a folder like /Library/Logs or ~/Library/Logs? How this can be achieved?

I tried by creating a folder in ~/Library/Logs using FileManager.createDirectory. But I think creating a file and write every time on it using file manager functions will make the app more complex.

Comment: I think you should look into [OSLog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) for your logging. (And I very much doubt that any normal apps logs to /Library/Logs)